# Mac OS X: How to draw multiple NSViews into a new, multi-page PDF?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have a graphics-related Document-based Mac App. My app's Documents may have multiple "pages". Each page has an `NSView` "canvas" object.

My app has several export options which are implemented as methods which return an `NSData` object (which is then written to disk).

I would like to implement a PDF export option in a method which:

1. Creates an in-memory PDF
2. loops thru my document's canvas views and renders each in a new page in the in-memory PDF
3. returns the in-memory, multi-page PDF as an `NSData`

The code below is what I am currently trying.

Each page in my document is 800 x 600 pixels.

When I write the resulting `NSData` object to disk, the write operation succeeds, but the file on disk is corrupted somehow. The file cannot be opened in Preview or any other app I've tried.

What am I doing wrong?

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSMutableData data];
CGDataConsumerRef consumer = CGDataConsumerCreateWithCFData((CFMutableDataRef)data);

CGRect mediaBox = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 600.0);
CGContextRef ctx = CGPDFContextCreate(consumer, &mediaBox, NULL);
CFRelease(consumer);

NSGraphicsContext *gc = [NSGraphicsContext graphicsContextWithGraphicsPort:ctx flipped:NO];

for (NSView *canvas in myCanvases) {
    CGContextBeginPage(ctx, &mediaBox);
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);

    [canvas displayRectIgnoringOpacity:mediaBox inContext:gc];

    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGContextEndPage(ctx);
}

CGPDFContextClose(ctx); // UPDATE: this line was originally missing. see answer below
CGContextRelease(ctx);

...

NSError *err = nil;
if (![data writeToFile:s options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&err]) {
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"%@", err);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a hex dump of maybe the first kilobyte of data?

Comment: Why are you exporting to a data object in memory? Why not export directly to the file?

Comment: I wonder if you could give me some input on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621858/best-practice-for-laying-out-images-for-printing-in-a-wysiwyg-mac-app/10623011#10623011 Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OP here. I have solved the problem. I was missing a final call to `CGPDFContextClose()`.

So before releasing the context...

```
CGPDFContextClose(ctx);
CGContextRelease(ctx);
```

Comment: I can't believe it was that simple, thanks! I wasted hours on this, as the bug was only happening when I started mixing NSString drawing (via AppKit extensions) on OS 10.10, but not on OS 10.9, so I was looking for something much more complicated. And it had worked before without closing the context, for months!

Answer (score 0):

I found this a most useful answer (and got to upvote the OP on both the question and the answer!). There were a few hiccups translating it into Swift 3, but this works like a charm, and it will work on iOS...

```
let data = NSMutableData()
guard let consumer = CGDataConsumer(data: data) else { Swift.print("Aargh - no CGDataConsumer"); return }
var mediaBox = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 800, height: 600)
guard let ctx = CGContext(consumer: consumer, mediaBox: &mediaBox, nil) else { Swift.print("Aargh - no CGContext"); return }

//let gc = NSGraphicsContext(cgContext: ctx, flipped: false) 
//I don't need the NS context, as my drawing routines just use CGContext

for page in self.pages { // Array of page models
    ctx.beginPage(mediaBox: &mediaBox)
    ctx.saveGState()
    myDraw(page, context: ctx, options: []) // My routine
    ctx.restoreGState()
    ctx.endPage()
}
ctx.closePDF()
do {
    try data.write(toFile: "/Users/grimxn/Test.pdf", options: .atomic)
} catch {
    Swift.print("Aargh - failed to write output file")
}
```